# Как вывести значение переменной за пределы функции

Tags: javascript, jquery

Мне нужно вынести значение `anketaObj` за пределы функции

```js
    var anketaObj;
        var params = {
            'IBLOCK_TYPE_ID': 'lists',
            'IBLOCK_ID': '110',
            // 'ELEMENT_CODE': 'element_1'
        };
        BX24.callMethod(
            'lists.element.get',
            params,
            function(result)
            {
                if(result.error())
                    alert("Error: " + result.error());
                else
                anketaObj = result.data()
                console.log(anketaObj)
                if (result.more())
                     result.next();
                return anketaObj

            }
```

Comment: `anketaObj = result.data()` — а эта строчка не выполняет ровно то, что ожидается? Присваивает значение во внешнюю переменную...

Comment: тем не менее я не могу её вывести за пределы

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Answer (score 2):

Значение переменной записать в функцию и передать ее результат, предварительно вернув данный результат.

```
function getVars() { 
 const a = 1; 
 const b = 2; 
 const v = 3;  
  
 return { 
  a: a, 
  b: b, 
  c: v
 } 
  
}  

function getArrIsObj(){ 
 const obj = getVars(); 
 return Object.values(obj); 
} 

const arr = getArrIsObj(); 

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: на моём примере можно показать?

Comment: Окей, давай на чистоту. Тебе стоит не задавать каждый первый вопрос, а попытаться понять, что хотя бы написал я, повторить этот код ручками, зайти на похожу статью, посмотреть их решения. Прочитать про область видимости и все получится!